# \parttoc does not appear when used in starred \part*

Tags: minitoc, starred-version

I am trying to create mini-ToC at the begenning of a `part` level utilizing `minitoc` package. It works fine for numbered `\part`, however, it is not rendered when using starred `\part*`. According to the documtentation, I added `\addstarredpart` after the `\part*` command. Here is the minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\begin{document}

    \doparttoc
    \tableofcontents

    \part*{Part one}
    \addstarredpart{Part one}
    \parttoc

    \chapter{Chapter one}   

    \section{Section one}
    \section{Section two}

    \chapter{Chapter two}

\end{document}
```

`*.toc` file content:

```
\partbegin 
\contentsline {starpart}{Part one}{3}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}Chapter one}{3}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}Section one}{3}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.2}Section two}{3}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {2}Chapter two}{4}
```

`*.ptc1` file content:

```
{\reset@font\ptcCfont\mtc@string\contentsline{chapter}{\noexpand \leavevmode \numberline {1}Chapter one}{\reset@font\ptcCfont 3}}
{\reset@font\ptcSfont\mtc@string\contentsline{section}{\noexpand \leavevmode \numberline {1.1}Section one}{\reset@font\ptcSfont 3}}
{\reset@font\ptcSfont\mtc@string\contentsline{section}{\noexpand \leavevmode \numberline {1.2}Section two}{\reset@font\ptcSfont 3}}
{\reset@font\ptcCfont\mtc@string\contentsline{chapter}{\noexpand \leavevmode \numberline {2}Chapter two}{\reset@font\ptcCfont 4}}
```

Tested using PdfLaTex.

EDIT: I got following warning during the build process:
`W0046(minitoc(hints)) You have attempted to insert (minitoc(hints)) empty parttocs.`

Comment: About the only difference between \part and \part* is the addition of \partbegin, which is used to SUPRESS the following from being included in \parttoc.

Comment: One would think that `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\partend}` right after \part* would end the suppression.  Alas, no.

Comment: BTW, I think I spotted a couple of bugs in minitoc.  There are two definitions of `\@spart` which are supposed to be recursive, but instead they simple replace the first definition with the second.  Also `\ifx\partbegin\partend` is true, so that `\partbegin` is actually treated as `\partend` (tested first).

Answer (score 1):

Since `\partbegin` is treated as `\partend`, that means the code `\addtocounter{ptc}{-1}` is never executed as was originally intended.  So I thought I would give it a try.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{minitoc}

\begin{document}
    \doparttoc
    \tableofcontents

    \clearpage
    \addstarredpart{Part one}% note the page number
    \part*{Part one}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\string\addtocounter{ptc}{-1}}%

    \parttoc

    \chapter{Chapter one}   

    \section{Section one}
    \section{Section two}

    \chapter{Chapter two}
\end{document}
```

---

A more permanent solutions is to redefine `\partbegin` and `\partend`.  One can even remove the tests.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\makeatletter
\def\@spart{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\partend}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\partbegin}%
  \ptc@spart}
\def\partbegin{\addtocounter{ptc}{-1}}
\def\partend{\immediate\closeout\tf@mtc
  \immediate\openout\tf@mtc=\jobname.mtc}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \doparttoc
    \tableofcontents

    \clearpage
    \addstarredpart{Part one}% note the page number
    \part*{Part one}

    \parttoc

    \chapter{Chapter one}   

    \section{Section one}
    \section{Section two}

    \chapter{Chapter two}
\end{document}
```

The main problem with fixing these bugs is that the manual has been using `\partbegin` where it should have been using `\partend`.  For backward compatibility, one will need to reverse their definitions and order of appearance.